# Restrict access to resources in war

Tags: websphere, war, web.xml

I have some files in my application outside of WEB-INF, this is all in a Websphere application server 6.0. Can I use a servler or a filter to restrict access to those files? as of now these files are accesible by url in the web browser.

I tried with a security-constraint like this in the web.xml but it was ignored due to security options being disabled.

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict access to resources</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted folders</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/AFSD/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/ASDF/pub/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/AFSD/test.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/test.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Without `Application Security` enabled, these settings will be ignored. So either you have to enable application security or implement it via your own filter.

Comment: We talked to IBM and for some reason they couldn't enable these settings so that's not an option. A filter is a good option for doing something like this then?

Comment: Yes, as long as these resources are in your application.